# trying to implement dynamic sql via function call

Tags: plsql

I am recently implementing the dynamic sql in my cide and quite new to the concept. I was trying with the following function that will take the column name and update the value via dynamic function call.However the function gives out an error while compiling.Please find the code as below:

```
function upd_tab(col_name in varchar2,val in number)
return pls_integer
is
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE EMPLOYEE1 SET '||col_name||'= :THE_VALUE WHERE EMP_NAME IN(:NAME1,:Nme2)'
using val,john,aaron;
RETURN SQL%ROWCOUNT;
END;
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I would say that `john` and `aaron` are not declared.

Comment: error: [ORA-06550: line 2, column 46:
PLS-00201: identifier 'COL_NAME' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 3, column 3:
PLS-00372: In a procedure, RETURN statement cannot contain an expression
ORA-06550: line 3, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.]

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to declare variables in the using clause. Hope below snippet helps.

```
FUNCTION upd_tab(
    col_name IN VARCHAR2,
    val      IN NUMBER)
  RETURN pls_integer
IS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE EMPLOYEE1 SET '||col_name||'= :THE_VALUE WHERE EMP_NAME IN(:NAME1,:Nme2)' USING val,'john','aaron';
  RETURN SQL%ROWCOUNT;
END;
```

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks a lot for looking into the issue..however when I tried the snippet you gave...its giving out the following error..                                        ORA-06550: line 2, column 46:
PLS-00201: identifier 'COL_NAME' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 3, column 3:
PLS-00372: In a procedure, RETURN statement cannot contain an expression
ORA-06550: line 3, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.